# How to get Memory Usage in a variable using shell script

Tags: shell, memory

I am using the following script to get memory usage value, I want this value in variable so that i can apply 'if' condition on that value.Please suggest

```
@echo off
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want

```
memory_usage=`free -m | awk 'NR==2{print $3*100/$2 }'`
if [ `echo "${memory_usage} > 90.0" | bc` -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo " > 90.0 "
else
    echo " <= 90.0 "
fi
```

Note how to save the result of command into variable, and how to compare floating-point number.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you please guide me how i can store only the numeric value in a variable and apply if condition on it.

Thanks

Comment: @MohsinInayatKhan Done.